# Convert string turtle-attribute to list in Netlogo

Tags: string, list, class, netlogo

I have turtles with attributes (names, roles, duration) that look like this:

```
names      "LE1123, LE1345, LE5366, LE9998"
roles      "farmer, agent, priest, boxer"
duration   "424, 654, 755, 976"
```

So they are a strings, with commas separating the words. Now, I want each word to be an item in a list, as such:

```
names      ["LE1123", "LE1345", "LE5366", "LE9998"]
roles      ["farmer", "agent", "priest", "boxer"]
duration   [424, 654, 755, 976] (as an int)
```

How would I achieve this? I cant seem to figure it out. Tried stuff with substring, comma position and fput into list in a while loop but it escapes me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the CSV extension for this.  It takes a comma-delineated string and turns it into a list. As an example:

```
extensions [csv]
to test
  let names "LE1123,LE1345,LE5366,LE9998"
  let roles "farmer,agent,priest,boxer"
  let duration "424,654,755,976"

  show csv:from-row names
  show csv:from-row roles
  show csv:from-row duration
end
```

Running `test` in the command center gives you

```
observer> test
observer: ["LE1123" "LE1345" "LE5366" "LE9998"]
observer: ["farmer" "agent" "priest" "boxer"]
observer: [424 654 755 976]
```

NOTE two things, however. First, lists do not have commas, just a space that delimits the items. You can see that in the output above.  Second, and more importantly,  the `from-row` does not like a comma followed by a space in the string.  It sees "A, B" (It may be hard to see, but that is "A,(space)B".) as having " B" as the second element and will output ["A" " B"].  Having the leading space for all but the first element in the list of strings may, or may not make a difference for you.  But it definitely makes a difference when you a parsing a string of numbers.  "1, 2" (that is "1,(space)2") is seen as having the number one as the first element, but the string " 2" as the second element. It thus yields the list [1 " 2"].  Not at all what you want. You will note that I've eliminated the spaces after commas in the example above.

I wish the extension was a bit smarter about this, but it's not.

Charles

Charles

Comment: Thanks! And I solved the white spaces issue by: set names remove " " names (etc.) before reading in the csv with csv:from-row!

Comment: Good thinking.  I had forgotten about remove.